# R ggplot Displaying text on graph in response to specific input

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Ok so I am making a web app using R Shiny that allows users to select a gene from a list of 19000 or so, and then view data and calculations associated with that gene. So far I have gotten the graphs and plots working fine (with some help from users here).

I am now trying to display annotations on my graph, so that when the user selects a gene which is in a specific list of highly enriched genes, a symbol or text appears on the graph above the column corresponding to the cell type to tell them that. The second list of genes is uploaded as a separate file.

I have gotten this working so far by using the annotate function within ggplot, and putting the x value  as the CellType so that the annotation appears above that specific cell. and it displays text well when a gene within that list is selected. The following is some mock data, and then a pared down version of the code to make the graph.

```
    Mean_list <-
      data.frame(Cells = factor(c("Celltype1", "Celltype2", "Celltype3", "Celltype4"), 
                                     levels =c("Celltype1", "Celltype2", "Celltype3", "Celltype4")),
                 Mean = c(mean(c(1, 2, 3)), mean(c(5, 8, 4)), mean(c(9, 8 ,3)), mean(c(3, 6, 8, 5))))


    output$celltype_bar_plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = Mean_list, aes(Cells, Mean, fill = Cells)) +
        annotate("text", x = GeneEnriched[GeneEnriched$X1 %in% input$gene_select, 2] label = "enriched") 
      })
```

The problem is when a gene NOT in that list is selected. If the GeneEnriched file ONLY contains the list of enriched genes then I get an error when selecting a gene not in the list. If The GeneEnriched contains all genes, but only has Celltype names in column 2  if the gene is enriched, then it inserts an additional column and messes up the order of the graph. Examples of the 2 types of GeneEnriched table I have tried are below.

GeneEnriched Type 1:

```
      X1          X2 
1   Gene1      Celltype1   
2   Gene3      Celltype3   
3   Gene4      Celltype4   
4   Gene24     Celltype3   
5   Gene52     Celltype1   
6   Gene54     Celltype2
```

GeneEnriched type 2:

```
      X1          X2 
1   Gene1      Celltype1   
2   Gene2        
3   Gene3      Celltype3   
4   Gene4      Celltype4   
5   Gene5       
6   Gene6
```

How can I get it so that the text appears when a gene in the secondary list is selected, but that nothing happens when a gene NOT in this secondary list is selected.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I figured it out. I hadn't realised you could use if statements within the ggplot2 argument itself. All I needed to do was wrap the 
`annotate("text", x = GeneEnriched[GeneEnriched$X1 %in% input$gene_select, 2] label = "enriched") ` with `if (input$gene_select %in% GeneEnriched2$X1) {}`

Comment: You may consider creating a `reactive` expression for your gene though. That will give you much cleaner code and take the logic of the gene selection out of your plot. Check out `shiny::reactive`.

Comment: I have reactives in other areas of my actual code, and it would work here provided all the genes were in the GeneEnriched table. The problem here though is if the gene selection is NOT in the GeneEnriched table, the annotate() function still expects an x value even when there isn't one and produces an error

Comment: You're right! In that case I'd still use a reactive which returns `geom_blank()` if no gene is selected or an `annotate()` layer otherwise but that's really a personal preference!